# Why is the apply() function needed in the constructor

Tags: javascript

```
function Set() {          // This is the constructor
    this.values = {};     
    this.n = 0;          
    this.add.apply(this, arguments);  // All arguments are values to add
}

// Add each of the arguments to the set.
Set.prototype.add = function() {
    /* Code to add properties to the object's values property */
    return this;
};
```

This is the beginning of the code used in "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" to create a 'Set' Class.  I've tried to rationalize the necessity of the [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function in the constructor but can not figure it out for the life of me.

```
this.add.apply(this, arguments);
```

if the `add()` function is already a method called by '`this`' then what purpose or use is the core [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function fulfilling.  Thanks in advance to anyone who attempts to explain this to me

http://jsfiddle.net/Marlin/Ydwgv/ - Full Example from Javascript: The Definitive Guide

Comment: It seems to serve little purpose. I have *never* seen it...

Comment: What are your thoughts on the fact that they are passing the arguments object?

Comment: you don't think it could have anything to do with ensuring that add() isn't added as a property of the instance instead of the prototype? i understand it isn't being declared...... but it sure is confusing me

Comment: Calling `.add()` doesn't add it as a property. `.apply()` is used here only so you can pass on all of the arguments to `.add()` that were sent to `Set()` all at once. If you knew that `Set()` would always get 2 arguments, then you'd just name them as parameters `Set( a, b )`, and do `this.add( a, b )`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"if the add() function is already a method called by 'this' then what purpose or use is the core apply() function fulfilling.*"

So that the `arguments` can be passed on as an entire collection. Useful if `Set` accepts an indefinite number of arguments.

Comment: Okay,  let me see if I've got this then.  add() accepts infinite arguments but doesn't accept a collection.  by using apply() you can bypass this restriction?

Comment: @Marlin Roughly speaking, yes ;-) Presumably the body of `add` iterates over the `arguments` object and does something with each element (where each element represents a parameter that the function was invoked with).

Comment: @Marlin: Yes, using `.apply()`, whatever number of individual arguments was passed to `Set()`, they will be passed on to `.add()` as individual arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't need in the constructor -- in fact, it has *nothing to do with a constructor in general* (but obviously it matters for this specific one ;-). What [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) *does* do is ensure that the target function is invoked "correctly".

That is, `apply`, when given an array-like object* (`arguments` counts), `[n1, n2, ... n3]` and a function `f`, it will call the target function as `f(n1, n2, ... n3)`. `apply` also takes the "this context" which is passed the newly created object in the code (to make it seem as though `add` was called "as a normal method"). See the link above for more information/examples.

That means, that for the code above,

```
var s = new Set(1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
var s = new Set()
s.add(1, 2, 3)
```

are equivalent.

Happy coding.

---

*In FireFox prior to 4 it had to be an Array-proper. This is why sometimes code uses the ugly idiom:

```
f.apply(context, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is being called not for the scope, but the fact that apply will take an array of arguments and pass them in order:

```
this.add.apply(this, [1,2,3,4]);
....
function add(one, two, three, four)
```

not a single parameter that is an array

Comment: perfect, I appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 1):

The `apply` method of a function allows you to invoke the function by passing an array instead of a list of items.

To illustrate:

```
function add(a, b) {
    return a+b;
}

var values = [1,2];

alert(add.apply(this, values));
```

will alert 3.

---

So, essentially, what you are doing there is allowing your constructor to take *any number* of arguments, and you will then pass them all in to the `add` function in one shot.

So, if you were to call your constructor with:

```
var stack = new Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

all of those values will be passed to the `add` function, as if you would have written:

```
this.add(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what i needed to know.  learned apply a few days ago, thought it was just used to call methods from different objects

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.apply()` syntax allows you to pass an array of arguments to the function being invoked. In this case it is passing the `arguments` object, which means it is calling `add()` with any and all of the parameters that were passed to the Set constructor function. So you can create new Set objects with an arbitrary number of values by saying, e.g.,

```
var mySet = new Set(13,42,18,19,44,11,5);
```

And all of those values will be passed through to `add()`.

Comment: thank you, my previous read of apply included that explanation but focused more on its ability to call a method from a different object